# Find ColdFusion Generated ID

Tags: coldfusion

Is there a way to find the elements generated by ColdFusion's `<CFLayout>` and `<CFLayoutArea>` tags?

These tags:

```
<cflayout type="tab" name="MyAccount">
<cflayoutarea name="OrderStatus" title="P" source="/o.cfm" />
```

Generate this code:

```
<td id="ext-gen31" style="width: 174px;">
<a id="ext-gen28" class="x-tabs-right" href="#">
<span class="x-tabs-left">
<em id="ext-gen29" class="x-tabs-inner" style="width: 154px;">
<span id="ext-gen30" class="x-tabs-text" title="P" unselectable="on" style="width: 154px;">
```

I want to update the title information in the id of ext-gen30 but don't know what that name is going to be or how to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't directly answer your question, but if your goal is to get a reference to the DOM objects in order to set their properties (and it sounds like that's the case), then the documentation suggests that you should be able to use the function [`ColdFusion.Layout.getTabLayout()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/JavaScriptFcns_14.html#1213054) to get a reference to the [Ext layout object](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/ext/docs/output/Ext.BorderLayout.html), and then manipulate that however you'd like.

Comment: Thanks very much!  Your answer led me down the path of the Ext object and the updates that were required.